# Create NSDictionary from Python dictionary

Tags: macos, nsdictionary, pyobjc

How do I get an NSDictionary from a Python dictionary (so that I can call `description` on it) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> d = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithDictionary_({"foo": "bar"})
>>> type(d)
<objective-c class __NSDictionaryI at 0x7fff7ae34688>
>>> d.description()
u'{\n    foo = bar;\n}'
>>> d
{
    foo = bar;
}
>>>
```